# Why would latency suddenly go up when crossing networks?

Tags: networking, latency, traceroute

I'm looking at the latency from my machine to a world of warcraft server.

Every hop while I am in Comcast's network is sub 15ms.

Then it hits ATT and goes to 60-70MS for the rest.

Why would it suddenly jump from 15 to 60 considering it's still in the same city?

Is there anything I can do about it?

G-Man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congested connection = long packet queue = latency
There's usually no way to avoid this besides switching your connection; even then other ISPs might use the same [Upstream ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider#ISP_interconnection).

Answer (score 5):

The inter-network link is slow. Not a damn thing you can do about it, short of switch ISPs.

Comment: Unless Comcast is hiddlenly throttling traffic again.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that MPLS tagged networks report the ping time as the RTT for the virtual circuit.  ICMP is also low priority, and, on a busy router can be dropped or delayed.  Also, some routers enforce rate limiting and when ICMP gets over a certain threshhold, it'll drop/delay those packets as well.

Additionally, you could be experiencing an asymmetric route.  Traffic that goes to that one router may return through a different route which may have more hops or congestion somewhere other than the path you see.  So, when you hit that one AT&T router, their internal policies, or Comcast's route announcements may prefer a different ingress than the router the packet just exited.